# To prove the existence of a derivative

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

**Problem**

Let $f(x,y)= \frac{xy^3}{x^3+y^6}$ if $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ ,and define $f(0,0)=0$.
Prove that the derivative $f'(O,a)$ exists for every vector $a$ and compute its value in terms of the components of $a$.

**Attempt**

$f'(O,a)= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(ha_1,ha_2)}{h}$ =0.

What i am doing wrong ?

NB- $a_1,a_2$ are components of $a$. O=(0,0)

Comment: What do you mean by 'O' in the equation? And how is $a$ a vector?

Comment: The function is not well defined. At the point $(-1,1)$ you will have division by zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing wrong depends upon the way how you deduced that that limit is equal to $0$. Anyway,\begin{align}\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(ha_1,ha_2)}h&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h^3a_1{a_2}^3}{h^3{a_1}^3+h^6{a_2}^6}\\&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{a_1{a_2}^3}{{a_1}^3+h^3{a_2}^6}\\&=\begin{cases}\frac{{a_2}^3}{{a_1}^2}&\text{ if }a_1,a_2\neq0\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{align}

Comment: But can we even talk about derivative when the function is not defined in infinitely many points, including points near the origin?

Comment: We can still talk about the *directional* derivative with respect to a given vector $v\neq0$, as long as $f$ is defined at $hv$ for every $h$ within some interval $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$

Comment: Oh, ok then. Sounds right.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos  thanks for answering. This question is from Apostal. I think there is an extra y in the numerator. If you look at your solution ,you have left out an h.

Comment: @blueboy Where? After the second $=$ sign?

Comment: No after the first

Comment: \begin{align}\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(ha_1,ha_2)}h&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h^**4**a_1{a_2}^3}{h^3{a_1}^3+h^6{a_2}^6}\\&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{a_1{a_2}^3}{{a_1}^3+h^3{a_2}^6}\\&=\begin{cases}\frac{{a_2}^3}{{a_1}^2}&\text{ if }a_1,a_2\neq0\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{align}

Comment: @blueboy The numerator of $f(ha_1,ha_2)$ is $h^4a_1{a_2}^3$, but then I divided by $h$.

Comment: My bad. Thanks.